# Passing kinect skeleton position data into another window

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I have two different windows, one will to display streams on a image and calculate a user's skeleton head position (window A), and another is display a 3D visual model that will use the skeleton data to zoom and translate(animation)(window B).

However, my problem is how can I suppose to pass and keep updating these skeleton head position data from window A to window B? I am using WPF and M'soft Kinect SDK. My another question is that how can I display a control like a button or a menu on the visual model as for my case the model is filled up the whole screen.

```
  foreach (Skeleton skeleton in skeletons)
    {
        if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
        {

            ht.GetHeadPosition(skeleton, out message, out headPosition);

            this.headPoint.X = headPosition.X;
            this.headPoint.Y = headPosition.Y;
            this.headPoint.Z = headPosition.Z;

            this.StatusTextBlock.Text = message;

        }
```

Edit

---

```
  public void newSensor_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (skeletonFrame == null)
                 return;

             GetSkeletons(skeletonFrame, ref skeletons);

             if (skeletons.All(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked))
                 return;

             //skeletonManager.Draw(skeletons);
        }

        foreach (Skeleton skeleton in skeletons)
        {
            if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                Joint headJoint = skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head];
                Joint hipCenter = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter];

                headPosition = headJoint.Position;

                this.headPoint.X = headPosition.X;
                this.headPoint.Y = headPosition.Y;
                this.headPoint.Z = headPosition.Z;

                message = string.Format("Head: X:{0:0.0} Y:{1:0.0} Z:{2:0.0}",
                headPoint.X,
                headPoint.Y, headPoint.Z);

                //MessageBox.Show(message);

                this.HeadPosition.Text = message;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't get the HeadPosition.Text update with the data.What actually happened?

kinect changed event handler at window A

```
    private void sensorChooser_KinectChanged(object sender, KinectChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        KinectSensor oldSensor = (KinectSensor)e.OldSensor;
        StopKinect(oldSensor);

        KinectSensor newSensor = (KinectSensor)e.NewSensor;

        if (newSensor == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Register for event and enable Kinect Sensor features you want
        newSensor.DepthFrameReady += newSensor_DepthFrameReady;
        newSensor.SkeletonFrameReady += mw.newSensor_SkeletonFrameReady;

        //newSensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
        newSensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);

       ....

        newSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(parameter);

        StartKinect(newSensor);

    }
```

XAML_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

```
  <Grid x:Name="firstGrid">
    <Viewport3D x:Name="viewPort" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ClipToBounds="False" Width="2048" 
    ....
    .....
    </Viewport3D>

    <TextBox x:Name="IndexPosition" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="485,2,0,0"   TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="CameraPosition" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="570,2,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142"/>

    <TextBlock Name="HeadPosition" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="492,23,0,0" Text="Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182" Height="29" 
               Foreground="Tomato" FontSize="20"/>
```

Comment: What is `ht.GetHeadPoistion` doing?  Directly accessing the `skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position` object will get you the same stuff -- without the weirdness of using `out` parameters.

Comment: Yes..I changed back to access it directly. At first i thought I can pass the value around from the GetHeadPosition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one of many different ways.  It all depends on how you want to seperate the code in your program.

**Option 1: Public Event Handlers**

You could set up public event handlers in `Window B` that subscribe to the `SkeletonFrameReady` event from the `KinectSensor`.  For example, in the class that sets up your `KinectSensor` you might have something like:

```
WindowB windowB = new WindowB();

private void InitializeKinectServices(KinectSensor sensor)
{
    // some setup code

    sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += windowB.OnSkeletonFrameReady;

    // some more setup code
}
```

Then in your `WindowB` class you would have the event callback:

```
public void OnSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        // do what you need
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Pass the Sensor**

You could set up your window(s) to accept a reference to the `KinectSensor`.  When you open the second window from your main class, just pass the sensor in:

```
WindowB windowB = new WindowB(sensor);
```

With your constructor of `WindowB` taking a `KinectSensor` and then setting up the callback from above:

```
public WindowB(KinectSensor sensor) {
    sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += OnSkeletonFrameReady;
}

private void OnSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        // do what you need
    }
}
```

Notice this allows your callback to be private.

**Option 3: Using a Framework Messenger**

You could also use a framework messenger, such as [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).  MVVM Light provides a lightweight messenger system that allows you to easily pass objects around from one view to the the next.  While this is more useful in a MVVM structured program that doesn't mean you can't use it outside one.

You can broadcast the entire `SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs` out from your main classes `SkeletonFrameReady` callback:

```
private void OnSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    Messenger.Default.Send<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(e);

    // do more stuff
}
```

Then you just need to subscribe to it from you `WindowB`:

```
public WindowB() {
    Messenger.Default.Register<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(this, OnSkeletonFrameReady);
}

private void OnSkeletonFrameReady(SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    // do what you need with the event arg, just as you would in a regular callback
}
```

Or you could just send the individual `Skeleton`, fromo your main class:

```
private void OnSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        // do checks for capturing the appropriate skeleton.

        Messenger.Default.Send<SkeletonFrame>(skeletonFrame);

        // do more stuff if you need.
    }
}
```

Your `WindowB` would then register, as shown above, on a `SkeletonFrame` instead of the event args.  The callback would do what it needs to do with the `SkeletonFrame` object.

**What's Best?**

Up to you.  There are several other ways you could ultimately do this.  These are the first three I thought of.  They will all accomplish the same thing -- you just want to use the one your are most comfortable with for your program style.

**Maximizing the Window**

To maximize the window, you can place a button in your XAML and setup a callback to toggle between the `Maximized` and `Normal` window state.

XAML:

```
<Button Click="MyButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
```

Code Behind:

```
bool _isMaxed = false;
public void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (_isMaxed)
      this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
  else
      this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

  _isMaxed = !_isMaxed;
}
```

Comment: I tried the first option and I think I managed to get the head position but something weird happened. I assigned a textblock to display and track the head position but it won't show up the value but instead, it did shown up when I use messagebox.show..

Comment: You'd need to include your XAML too.  The code itself looks fine, but half the picture is missing from your post (i.e., the XAML).

Comment: Not sure.  It basically looks correct.  It might be due to something else updating the value outside the loop, or the loop itself updating `message` to something different very quickly.  Put a `Debug.WriteLine()` statement in there to see what comes out when you run it.

Comment: Put like this? Debug.WriteLine(message); By the way, I got this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at this.HeadPosition.Text = message; The Autos shows   message "Head: X:0.3 Y:0.6 Z:1.7" string
this {WpfApplication1.MainWindow} WpfApplication1.MainWindow
this.HeadPosition null System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
It shows the message contains the correct head position, just the textbox won't update as it shown null. I am confuse.

Comment: Is your `HeadPosition` `TextBlock` defined in the `MainWindow` or your second window?  Are you referencing it after you call `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: I defined it in mainwindow which supposed to pass the event handler  from the second window. If like that do I still need to referencing it?

Comment: If your `HeadPosition` `TextBlock` is defined in `MainWindow.xaml` and your `this.HeadPosition.Text` reference is in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, I don't know what the problem is.  I'd suggest starting a new question to address that concern.

Comment: Okay..I will take some sleep then come back to this again..Anyway thanks for your kindness to explain and reply me regarding my doubts..I will try another options that you mentioned above later on. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to pass the head position back into the second window to display its worked. So, I just leave it like that as it just for the display and tracking purposes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass the Skeleton to your second window (e.g. in constructor) and use its OnHeadPositionChanged-Event.
2. Just add the control in the xaml and set fix positions, like `Margin="0,10,0,10"`, or use a Canvas as parent and set the position through `Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="20"`.

Comment: Passing the `Skeleton` to the window constructor will not work, as it is a simple data object with no events.

Comment: @Florian Hi..I tried passing by constructor before but seems like can't work..hmm..

Comment: @Evil Closet Monkey..Do you have any idea about my first question? Edit: Just saw that reply is yours..haha..sorry.

Comment: About reacting to the `SkeletonFrameReady` event in both windows?  Yes... I wrote a *really* long answer to it below.